Integer valued polynomials and divided power algebra
Let $T\subset \mathbb Q[x]$ be the ring of integer valued polynomials, i.e. the polynomials $f$ with $f(\mathbb Z)\subset \mathbb Z$. In his wonderful book ”Commutative algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry”, Exercise 1.21(c), Eisenbud asks the reader to prove that $T$ is (EDIT: not) noetherian. He then adds ”We shall meet $T$ again as a free divided power algebra in Appendix A2”.
Am I missing something obvious here? First of all I can’t find any mention of $T$ in Appendix A2 and secondly I dont see how $T$ can support a divided power structure since $x$ belongs to $T$ but $\frac{x^2}{2}$ does not.

I don't have that reference in front of me, but I'm pretty sure that the ring of integer valued polynomials is not noetherian. For example, ideal of polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(0) = 0$ is not finitely generated...

@Nate Thanks! I missed a crucial ”not”.  A reference for non-noetherianness of $T$ is Cahen & Chabert, ”Integer-Valued Polynomials”, Proposition V.2.7. However, this wasnt my real question.

$T$ is not the free divided power algebra in one generator, but the free binomial ring in one generator.

@Z. M Ok, thanks. So this is actually a slip up in Eisenbuds book I guess.
